# AWS Data Transfer Costs within the same machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ECS cluster of services running on a few EC2 machines. Each service is internet facing and forms a target group, all these target groups are on the same load balancer.

```
Architecture:
Service 1 -> TG1 -> ELB
Service 2 -> TG2 -> ELB

ELB Rules:
If request from 1.domain.com -> route to Service 1
If request from 2.domain.com -> route to Service 2
```

The services communicate with one another via their public CNAMEs.

I'm trying to figure out data-out transfer costs when Service 1 communicates with Service 2 by calling an endpoint on 2.domain.com. I think we'd be charged at the same rate as data-out to public internet even though the services are in the same region (could literally be hosted on the same machine), as the communication doesn't happen through a private IP but through the public internet. I've consulted the AWS documentation and can't find anything related to confirm this. Can someone help with this please?

Edited to Add: My AWS bill reflects data out charges because we use several public services and we provide information to clients outside the network. I want to know if this specific case is charged as well.

Comment: What does your AWS bill say when you try it?

Comment: [OpenGuide](https://github.com/open-guides/og-aws) may help, specifically [this picture](https://github.com/open-guides/og-aws/raw/master/figures/aws-data-transfer-costs.png).

Comment: Updated my question to include billing output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are accessing a service within the same server or VPC, if you access that service through the public IP address, then the connection will exit your VPC and re-enter. This will incur outgoing data transfer costs.

To access a service within the same VPC (or within the same server) without incurring data transfer costs, use the private IP address or localhost/127.0.0.1 (if the service is on the same server).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I have multiple tasks to a service, all of them behind a load balancer, plus dynamic port management by ECS. So I don't think I can access using the private IP or localhost.

Comment: If your load balancer was *internal only*, then you could access it via the internal IP addresses and that wouldn't incur any data transfer costs.